# HOW TO reconfigure git user?

Tags: git

I've just got a friend's computer and I need to reconfigure the GIT to my user account.
I read that you can change the user name by typing `git config --global user.name "My Name"` but this probably won't change the user itself, just its name.

Any hints?
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't care about your user name. Well, yes, it cares in *one* situation:

- if you do not have `user.name` setup, it will default to the system's user name;
- if you do not have `user.email` configured, it will by default append the system username, '@', and the hostname of the machine you are on;

So, in the end, you really have to ensure about two things:

- you have a `user.name` and `user.email` properly set;
- your "new user" has the necessary privileges to operate the repository.

Also note that the name and email settings may be overwritten on a *per repository basis*. Check the `.git/config` of existing repositories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Git global user config values are saved in the user path. So if you are logging in with a different user account, you can set the global config values and it basically takes those user values, leaving the former user's values in tact under their account.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you connect to the repository. For one, the username could be hardcoded in the remote repository's URL (e.g. `ssh://user@hostname/my/repository.git` -- you can check with `git remote -v`). In this case you can just change the remote URL using `git remote set-url origin ssh://...`.

If you use SSH to connect, the username could also be configured in the SSH configuration file (on UNIX in `~/.ssh/ssh_config`). Then, some services use the client's SSH key to identify the user (in which case you would probably have to switch your SSH key).

If you are authenticating anonymously, you can just change the config settings.